# PowerShell Not Returning to command line after running "dotnet run ..."

Tags: c#, powershell, service

I'm currently trying to build a PowerShell script that need to start my own C# application as Service and then after I need to check back the event log for error or other entry. But as soon as the dotnet run task is done, the process won't let me run another command, it seam to wait for the started process to stop.

Here a example of PowerShell script

```
CD C:\MyCSharpProject\Project\ 
dotnet run --debug <# script stop after this command is run, and the next command is not run r#>
notepad <# This line is never hit #>
```

How can I start my service and then run another command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Start-Process` to run something without waiting.

Example:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet' -WorkingDirectory 'C:\MyCSharpProject\Project' -ArgumentList 'run --debug'
notepad
```